# Switch operator

Tags: c

Basic switch operator error in a c program utilising VS code. Any input I provide always returns the default function. Please assist me.

[Code used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x2JT.png)

Comment: The compiler output is telling you what to do.  Case 1, not Case1.  etc (you need spaces between the case keyword and the digit).

Comment: [Do not post images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question); post the code in the question.

Comment: C is both case-sensitive and spacing sensitive: `Case1:` is radically different from `case 1:`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you should have `Case1` be `case 1`, `Case2` be `case 2`, etc. The compiler thinks that `Case1:` is a `goto` label, not `case 1:` as it should have been. That's why the compiler didn't alert you and jumped straight to the default.

Comment: Thank you very much tsoa, tho if you are free could you kindly explain "the compiler thinks that Case1: is a goto label, not case 1: as it should have been". I understand the part that it needed to be small not big, is that because of the format

Comment: Yes, it's because C is case-sensitive. Upper case "Char" is not the same as lower case "char", for instance. Same with variables. If you had variable "Bob", the compiler would not recognize "BOB" as the same thing as "Bob". Hope this helps!